# Find the general term of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$, $x_{n}\in \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence with $x_{1}\in [\frac{1}{2},\infty )$ and $$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}^{3}}{3x_{n}^{2}-3x_{n}+1}$$
Find the general term of the sequence.

Attempts:

I though of solving the ecuation $3r^{3}-3r^{2}+r=r^{3}$ , that has the roots $r_{1}=0, r_{2}=\frac{1}{2}, r_{3}=1$

I aslo noticed that$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}^{3}}{(1-x_{n})^{3}+x_{n}^{3}}$$

What is the fomula for the general term? I can't find a conection with $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}+\alpha }{x_{n}+\beta }$ or $x_{n+1}=\alpha x_{n}+\beta x_{n-1}$ or is  there another method?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idea of identifying the cubes was a fantastic spot. Regarding solving the equation that you did : That's not the equation you need to solve, but a similar one. One should also be looking out for the well-definition of the RHS of the definition i.e. proving , for example, that $x_n$ is positive for all $n$. That is clear once one sees that $3x^2-3x+1 > 0$ for all $x >0$.

Once you do this, then you need to cleverly retain any created cubes : essentially , weed out the troublesome $3x_n^2-3x_n+1$. That isn't difficult to do. Indeed, if $$
x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n^3}{3x_n^2-3x_n+1}
$$

then subtracting $1$ from both sides$$
x_{n+1}-1 = \frac{x_n^3-3x_n^2+3x_n-1}{3x_n^2-3x_n+1} = \frac{(x_n-1)^3}{3x_n^2-3x_n+1}
$$

Now, IF $x_n \neq 1$ and $x_{n+1}\neq 1$, then dividing one equation by the other will retain the cubes as well as get rid of the troublesome $3x_n^2-3x_n+1$. When we do it, we get  $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-1} = \left(\frac{x_n}{x_n-1}\right)^3$$

which , provided we can retain the inequality to $1$ at each point, instantly leads to the following iterated situation :$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-1} = \left(\frac{x_n}{x_n-1}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1}-1}\right)^9 = \left(\frac{x_{n-2}}{x_{n-2}-1}\right)^{27} 
$$
and so on , till we get to :$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-1} =  \left(\frac{x_1}{x_1-1}\right)^{3^{n}}
$$

which can be easily solved to yield a formula for $x_{n}$ only in terms of $x_1$ and $n$. Indeed, $$
x_{n+1} = \frac{\left(\frac{x_1}{x_1-1}\right)^{3^{n}}}{\left(\frac{x_1}{x_1-1}\right)^{3^{n}}-1}
$$

---

The IF case, requires solving an equation.

Indeed, IF $x_n =1$, then $x_{n+1} = 1$ by substitution, so the sequence is a constant $1$ afterwards.

On the other hand, if $x_{n+1} = 1$, then $x_n$ must satisfy $r^3 = 3r^2-3r+1$ so that $r = 1$ is forced from here. So $x_n = 1$ as well. In other words, if a $1$ ever appears in the sequence, then the only possibility is that the sequence is the constant sequence $1$.

Thus, we can complete our reasoning from here.

Comment: +1 for building upon OP's approach, which wasn't obvious (to me) that could be worked out.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, I had the hunch they'd done the very important work of finding the cube. I could figure the rest out, thankfully.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have thought of dividing $x_{n+1}$ with $x_{n+1}-1$.

Comment: @Sd100 you are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\;$ let $\,y_n = \dfrac{1}{x_n}\,$, invert both sides, then complete a cube.

$$y_{n+1}\color{red}{-1}=y_n^3-3y_n^2+3y_n\color{red}{-1}$$

Comment: How did you think of that transformation? Is there a systematic way to arrive at it? Or did you just try a few things?

Comment: @StefanLafon The expression suggests than working in $\,1/x_n\,$ may simplify the relation and, indeed, it transforms it from a rational function to a polynomial one. Not only that, but a polynomial which turns out to be close to a familiar form.

Comment: @StefanLafon: the powers and the coefficients $3,-3,1$ evoke the binomial development of $(1-x)^3$. These terms at the denominator call for an inversion.